# Eclipse Plugin- How to execute UNIX command from eclipse plugin?

Tags: unix, eclipse-plugin

I am writing an eclipse plugin that will take input of a file name, pass that to a UNIX command and get the output back (The command is to get file path of entered file name from CVS repository). My basic plugin code is under development, but I am not finding any info on how can I execute UNIX commands from eclipse. Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[Runtime.exec(...)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) from the Java standard library should do what you need to execute UNIX shell commands that are in your path of the user that is executing eclipse.  If you want to call UNIX C libraries API you can use [the JNA library](https://github.com/twall/jna).